# How could I check whether strtol parsed anything at all?

Tags: c, winapi, strtol

[`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) parses out a long integer from a given string. Okay. But how could I check whether there was parsed anything at all?

For example:

- using `strtol` on the following string yields `0`:
   `0abcdef`
- however, using `strtol` on the following string yields `0` too:
  `abcdef`

So, I have no indicator whether the function parsed a valid `0` or did not parse anything at all and thus returns `0`.

How do I verify whether `strtol` worked correct or returned with an error? Are there any alternatives?

[I read that `strtol` sets an errno](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) on Unix, but I'm especially interested in the Win32 platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the signature of strtol():

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

If `endptr` is not NULL, `strtol()` stores the address of the first invalid character in `*endptr`.
So you can simply compare `*endptr` to `nptr` afterwards and if it differs, `strtol()` has parsed the characters before `*endptr`.

Comment: It's not necessarily the first invalid character - for example an initial sequence of whitespace is valid, but even if the string starts with whitespace, if no conversion is performed then it is guaranteed that the value of `nptr` will be stored in `*endptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the second parameter of strtol : it's a `char **`. It will be filled with the first invalid char: [take a look at this manpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4z2wdyc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char       *ptr = 0;
    const char *str = "1234abcd";

    printf("%d\n", strtol(str, &ptr, 10)); // -> 0
    printf("ptr: %c\n", *ptr); // -> 'a'
    while (*str && *str != *ptr)
    {
        printf("parsed: %c\n",  *str); // -> '1' '2' '3' & '4'
        ++str;
    }
    return 0;
}
```